# T SQL Mesclar Duas linhas em Uma

Tags: sql-server, select, tsql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho um id em comum (103307) e gostaria de unir duas linhas em uma.
Da imagem 1 e deixar como a imagem 2. É possível?

Comment: A coluna untitled2, da primeira consulta, terá sempre os valores 1 e 2 para indicar a primeira e segunda linhas?

Answer (score 1):

Considerando-se que a coluna `Untitled2` conterá a ordenação da linha, para um mesmo valor de id, eis sugestão utilizando pivô clássico:

```
-- código #1
SELECT id, 
       max(case when C1 = 1 then 1 end) as nC1,
       max(case when C1 = 1 then C2 end) as nC2,
       max(case when C1 = 2 then 2 end) as nC3,
       max(case when C1 = 2 then C2 end) as nC4
  from tabela
  group by id;
```

No código acima `C1` é a coluna `Untitled2` e `C2` é a coluna `Untitled3`, considerando-se a primeira imagem.

---

A título de curiosidade, eis outra solução:

```
-- código #2
SELECT T1.id, 
       T1.C1 as nC1, T1.C2 as nC2,
       T2.C1 as nC3, T2.C2 as nC4
  from tabela as T1
       left join tabela as T2 on T1.id = T2.id
  where T1.C1 = 1
        and (T2.id is null or T2.C1 = 2);
```

Comment: A solução 1 resolveu meu problema. Obrigado. Porque não poderia fazer JOIN, já que não tenho duas tabelas, ainda mais que na verdade a "tabela" é um sub-select

Answer (score 0):

**Sugestão 1**

Se a coluna `untitled2` for um sequencial para registros do mesmo `id`, a query pode ser a seguinte:

```
select t1.untitled1
      ,t1.untitled2
      ,t1.untitled3
      ,t2.untitled2 as untitled3 
      ,t2.untitled3 as untitled4
  from tabela as t1
  join tabela as t2 on t1.untitled1 = t2.untitled1
 where t1.untitled2 < t2.untitled2;
```

**Solução 2**

Se os valores contidos em `untitled2` e `untitled3` puderem se repetir para registros de mesmo `id`, como, por exemplo:

```
untitled1 untitled2 untitled3 
103307    1         10
103307    1         10
```

Nesse caso, como podemos ter registros duplicados na tabela, será necessário criar um `idrow` para distinguir os registros.

Usando [SqlServer CTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql), podermos montar uma subquery para adicionar a coluna `idrow` antes de fazer o join para gerar o resultado final:

```
with tab_temp (idrow, untitled1, untitled2, untitled3)
as
(
   select row_number() over (order by untitled1)  as idrow
         ,untitled1
         ,untitled2
         ,untitled3
     from tabela
)
select t1.untitled1
      ,t1.untitled2
      ,t1.untitled3
      ,t2.untitled2 as untitled3 
      ,t2.untitled3 as untitled4
  from tab_temp as t1
  join tab_temp as t2 on t1.untitled1 = t2.untitled1
  where t1.idrow < t2.idrow;
```

**Para Teste**

Criei um exemplo rodando online em http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c7ae9e/11